# How to use AngularStrap's popover in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I have a service where I need to call a popover

```
.factory('BetSlipFactory', function($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('line:lineStatus', function(ev, status) {
   if (!processingLineMoves) {

      //HERE I NEED TO CALL THE POPOVER

    }

  });
};
```

so, I thought that by doing:

```
$rootScope.$on('line:lineStatus', function(ev, status) {
   if (!processingLineMoves) {
         $rootScope.popover = {
            "title": "Title",
            "content": "Hello Popover!"
          };
   }
});
```

but, it is not doing anything...

so, I will like to know how to call this popover in a service.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? According to http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers there are several ways to set up a popover (using a simple object, data-attrs, template or $popover service). I guess you are trying the simple object way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var myPopover = $popover(element, {
    title: 'My Title',
    content: 'My Content',
    trigger: 'manual'
});
myPopover.$promise.then(function() {
    myTooltip.show();
});
```